# Java PATH issue when installing JDK7 on centos 32 bit

Tags: path, java

I have Installed JDK 7 on CentOS 32 bit virtual machine. I also have set the path for java.  In one terminal it is showing java1.7  But when I open another terminal and look for, java -version It is showing java1.4

Comment: Where have you set the path? In e.g ~/.bashrc ?

Comment: Run `which java` and `echo $PATH` on both shells, and attach the output

Comment: CentOS does not user 'alternative' command for this? '/usr/sbin/alternatives –install /usr/bin/java java /usr/java/latest/bin/java 20000'

Comment: How did you install Java? Via the RPMs or as a tarball? http://www.if-not-true-then-false.com/2010/install-sun-oracle-java-jdk-jre-7-on-fedora-centos-red-hat-rhel/

Answer (score 0):

That's just because you probably set the path for java using `export` in a terminal. That will only work for the current session (terminal).

To make it permanent, you would have to add the `export` line you used to your `~/.bashrc` file.